# Возникает исключение при запросе на удаление строки из таблицы

Tags: java, mysql

Возникает исключение:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

при выполнении метода

```
 public void Delete(int id){
    try{
        statement.execute("DELETE FROM products WHERE idproducts = id");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Запрос написан, по-моему, верно, не могу понять в чем причина ошибки.

Comment: Какого типа у вас поле idproducts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш запрос - строка. Должно быть что-то такое:

```
public void Delete(int id){
    try{
        statement.execute("DELETE FROM products WHERE idproducts = " + id);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите искать по id который передали в функцию, то надо писать:

```
"DELETE FROM products WHERE idproducts = " + String.valueOf(id)
```

З.Ы. совет - функции называйте с маленькой буквы

Comment: Спасибо за совет